# How to re-initialise jQuery bxSlider when resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, bxslider

I'm working on the site: http://bit.ly/zzX4om

And I've become stuck. When the browser window is resized, the bxSlider slideshow stays fixed in position.

Any ideas on where to go next?

Comment: What do you want to do actually?

Comment: I am looking for this as well.  You are trying to reload your slider when the browser resizes.  My use case is ipad portrait vs landscape.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the slider after window resize

```
slider = $("#slider").bxslider();

$(window).resize(function(){
   slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

Comment: @JuanSolano weird indeed and i'm lazy to investigate further i think this also started recently because I ran into it "about a week ago" :-) but didn't continue with my curiosity.